# SDS Max bit in SDS Plus drill

Tags: adapter

Is there an adapter that would allow me to use an sds max chisel (or other) bit in a sds plus drill? The max bits are quite a bit longer and would lessen the amount i need to bend over :). Looking to use at least a 600mm long bit.

Comment: google `SDS Plus 600 mm` ... the search should return some hits

Comment: Im seeing only sds max bits in the results. Are you getting different results? As mentioned im looking for chisel bits.

Comment: https://www.amazon.co.uk/PLUS-Chisel-Long-Pointed-Spade/dp/B00FW4299E/ref=mp_s_a_1_3?dchild=1&keywords=sds+chisel+600mm&qid=1595835933&sr=8-3

Comment: Thanks but i cannot be delivered to where i live. Hoping there is an adapter out there.

Comment: If you tell us where you live (a country, at least) you may get a better recommendation. Also, not sure if they're made, but you might consider looking for a bit extension to make you Plus bits longer.

Comment: Im from Australia

Comment: Extension bar seems like a good alternative to an adapter. Thanks.